# Firefox: Drawing video on canvas results sometimes in this error "AbortError: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user"

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, video, konvajs

I'm trying to draw a video on canvas with konva.js. It works great, but sometimes I have this error only in Firefox:

> AbortError: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user

As a user, I never intentionally aborted the process by clicking on something or changing the website.

This is my code for waiting until all videos are loaded:

```js
$(elements).each((index, item) => {
            const video = $(item).find('.slider-list__video')[0];

            const tryVideo = (readyVideo, readyIndex) => {
                if (readyVideo.readyState > 3) {
                    this.videosReady[readyIndex] = true;
                } else {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        tryVideo(readyVideo, readyIndex);
                    }, 100);
                }
            };
            tryVideo(video, index);
        });
```

This is my code when all videos are ready to display on the different layers of the stage in konva.js:

```js
$($('.slider-list__item').get().reverse()).each((index, item) => {
                const video = $(item).find('.slider-list__video')[0];
                this.videos.unshift(video);

                const layer = new Konva.Layer();
                layer.hitGraphEnabled(false);
                layer.listening(false);
                this.stage.add(layer);

                const image = new Konva.Image({
                    image: video,
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                });

                const group = new Konva.Group({
                    clipFunc(ctx) {
                        ctx.rect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    },
                });
                group.listening(false);

                group.add(image);
                layer.add(group);

                this.layers.unshift(layer);
                this.groups.unshift(group);

                this.videoStartAnimations.unshift(new Konva.Animation((() => {
                }), layer));
                this.initialized[index] = true;
});
```

As I said, this code works perfectly in all browsers. Just the Firefox browsers keeps throwing this error once in 10 times.